# Can't run an iOS app in React-Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm having multipronged issues to being able to run an iOS app through with react-native.

I've just set everything up and when I do run `react-native run-ios`, my build fails due to 'Port 8081 already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly'. Okay, I see this issue is addressed in the docs so I try the solutions.

1) **kill - 9 PID:**
McAfee seems to occupying Port 8081 on my machine and SIGKILL doesn't seem to work. The process does not get terminated whatsoever.

2) **Using a port other than 8081:**
I can't seem to open the in-app Developer menu by Command⌘ + D or selecting 'Shake Gesture', for me to specify a change in port. Neither of these seem to do anything at all.

Has anyone come across these issues?

Answer (score 0):

1) So no React-Native Issue. Can't help here.
2) You do not define the PORT inside the app, this makes no sense... How should it tell the packager to use a specific port if it can not connect to it.
Instead you should start the packager with `react-native start --port 3000` and adapt the port in all iOS and Android files where it is set. (Find in Project)

Answer (score 0):

Both methods can't change the port that iOS simulator under npm is running.